# Intel OneAPI setvarsh.sh not set pernamently (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, intel, intel-vtune, intel-oneapi

I am struggling with the usage of intel OneAPI, specifically compiler (DPC++/C++) and Vtune Profiler.

I've installed everything successfully, used `source setvarsh.sh` in the installation directory and everything worked fine until I closed the shell.

It appears that after setting the environmental variables they only last in an active terminal session and do not stay with me permanently. Directly after using `source setvars.sh` I am able to use `icx` or `vtune-gui` command. After starting new session I get only `command not found` error.

Is it something wrong with the script or should I use a specific switch or something?

System info: 
System: **Ubuntu 22.04. LTS 64-bit** 
GNOME Version: **42.0** 
Shell: **Zsh** 
Vtune Profiler: **2022.1.0.98** 
Intel Compiler: **2022.0.2.84**

For now I've solved the problem partially by adding an alias in `.zshrc` to run the `setvars.sh` script using one command but that seems like a very non-elegant solution. I'd appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior, `source` can only affect the current environment. [There is no "nice" way to set the environment variables permanently from a script, you need to edit your config files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117467).

What you can do is to automatically setup the environment when starting a new `zsh` session. That can be done by adding `source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` to your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Traditionally, env vars only need to be set from your `.profile` or `.zsh_profile` (once per *login*, not when starting subshells like if you run `zsh` at the command line).  But some desktop environments don't run each terminal window as a login shell, but also don't get env vars from your profile, so yes the easy way is to redo it in `.zshrc`, although that can lead to redundant `$PATH` entries if the script doesn't check for a path already being in `$PATH`.